# pan tool and wheel zoom not working after recreation of bokeh plot

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, bokeh

I am using bokeh for interactive data visualization. My need is to recreate a bokeh plot in dropdown callback. I am able to recreate a plot in callback but toolbar is not working in recreated plot. I am using following code.

```
fig=''
select=Select(title="Select")
def create_figure(attribute='Title'):
    global fig;
    fig=figure(x_axis_type='datetime',plot_width=1000,plot_height=600,tools=['pan','crosshair','wheel_zoom'])

def select_onchange(attr, old, new):
    global fig
    attribute=select.value
    create_figure(attribute)
    lay.children[2]=fig

create_figure()
lay = layout([[count_of_server],[widgetbox(select)],[fig],[widgetbox(button)]])
curdoc().add_root(lay)
```

I am using bokeh 0.12.14

Comment: I tried with bokeh 0.12.15, it works.

Comment: Did  you use same code as that of mine?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox

def app3(doc):
    fig=None
    select=Select(title="Select", options=["A", "B"], value="A")
    def create_figure(attribute='Title'):
        nonlocal fig
        fig=figure(x_axis_type='datetime',plot_width=400,plot_height=200,
                   tools=['pan','crosshair','wheel_zoom'], title=attribute)
        fig.circle(np.random.randn(100), np.random.randn(100))

    def select_onchange(attr, old, new):
        nonlocal fig
        attribute=select.value
        create_figure(attribute)
        lay.children[1].children[0]=fig

    select.on_change("value", select_onchange)

    create_figure()
    lay = layout([[widgetbox(select)],[fig]])
    doc.add_root(lay)

show(app3)
```